# Multivariate Time Series with Long Horizon Prediction

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis

There must be a model for what I would like to do, because I have been spending far too long with this project for an answer not to exist.  For reference, I am using R.

---

I have a time series object, $X$, with $n$ observations and $p$ columns (indicator variables).  I also have a separate time series object $y$ which I would like to predict *future* values of, which has $n$ observations and $1$ column.

I would like to feed this data into a black box, and I would like the black box to spit out $h$ predicted future values of object $y$ using learned patterns from my independent time series object X.

Of course one could find a simple linear solution using regression, but this does not account for obvious autocorrelation.  It *also* requires me to forecast dummy observations for $X$, ***which is undesirable***.  I would only like to forecast one series, not all of them.

I could also use an ARIMA model, which takes care of autocorrelation but has very poor predictive ability.

I looked into using `bsts`-type models, but these also require additional `newdata` when the object has a regression component.

I have been looking into `keras`-based models as well, but thus far have not found a solid tutorial to teach me what I am looking to learn.

---

**To reiterate:**

- **Time series $X_{n \times p}$**
- **Time series $y_{n \times 1}$**
- **Insert $X$ and $y$ into black box**
- **Supply value $h$, the desired time steps in the future I would like to predict**
- **See $h$ predicted values of $y$ based on features the machine learned during processing.**

---

Tutorials and/or walkthrough links would be greatly appreciated, especially if they are coded in R!

---

This question was tagged as a duplicate of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353595/deep-learning-model-lstm-with-temporal-and-non-temporal-attributes), which I had seen earlier.  However, the answer was not satisfying to me.  I feel this question is better worded, more nuanced, and asks specifically for some type of starter-code or tutorial, or information on how to begin implementation.  [This is one of the most useful guides I have found](https://robotwealth.com/deep-learning-trading-fighting-overfitting-dropout-regularization/), but in some regards it falls short (it does not explain how to accomplish far-in-the-future prediction).  The theory of machine learning is interesting for all of us, but as noted in [this journal entry](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0180944),

> Considering the complexity of financial time series, combining deep learning with financial market prediction is regarded as one of the most charming topics. **However, this field still remains relatively unexplored.**

In posing this question, I am hoping to assist other beginners with the same problem they face when attempting to incorporate time series forecasting with deep learning.

Comment: This is nicely worded & nuanced (+1). However, requests for code & tutorials are off topic here. The rest seems to be covered at the link.